# not able to run the first run.py of eve

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I'm trying to learn eve to use it to expose a database and I'm starting from the beginning [eve first step](http://python-eve.org/quickstart.html).

**run.py**

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

**settings.py**

```
DOMAIN = {'people': {}}
```

**requirements.txt**

```
scrapy==0.24.4
eve==0.5
pymongo==3.0.1
```

**`python run.py`**

```
   eve.io.base.ConnectionException: Error initializing the driver. Make sure the database serveris running. Driver exception: ConfigurationError('Unknown option auto_start_request',)
```

what's wrong? Why is there a problem with the database although I followed exactly what is in the `eve` quickstart?

- `virtualenv --version`: 12.0.7
- `pip -V`: 6.1.1
- `python --version : 2.7.6`
- `MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9`

Comment: Check your connection to MongoDB:

1- Is the service running?
2- Do you neeed credentials to access?

Comment: yes the service `mongod` is running and I don't need any credentials, I've just installed `mongodb` and everything to try `eve`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are running PyMongo 3.0.1 which breaks backward compatibility in a big way. If you look into [Eve requirements](https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/blob/develop/setup.py#L17) you will find that it requires PyMongo 2.8 (actually it's 2.7.x in production; 2.8+ on the development branch).

If you got PyMongo 3.0.1, then I suspect that you installed the requirements by hand. The  ideal way to install Eve (or any other Python library really) is to pip install from PYPI, even better if in a virtualenv; see [installation](http://python-eve.org/install.html) page.

For the record, a PyMongo 3.0.1 compatibile branch is ready on GitHub, but it is currently relying on a Flask-PyMongo fork since the current Flask-PyMongo release is not compatible with PyMongo 3+. Also, if you want to run MongoDB 3.0 with Eve you can do that. PyMongo 2.8 is fully compatibile with MongoDB 3.0.